# How to match a pattern which is repeated more than nth times non consecutively?

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to match a pattern "city, state" (e.g., "Austin, TX") on this sample vector

```
> s <- c("Austin, TX", "Forth Worth, TX", "Ft. Worth, TX", 
"Austin TX", "Austin, TX, USA", "Ft. Worth, TX, USA")

> grepl('[[:alnum:]], [[:alnum:]$]', s)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

However, there are two cases I would like to retrieve a FALSE:

-when there are more than 1 comma (i.e., `"Austin, TX, USA"`)

-when there is another punctuation sign before the comma (i.e.,`"Ft. Worth, TX"`)

Comment: Where are the quantifiers and the anchors? Spaces between two words are not described too.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I don't know how to use them. I know I could match two or more commas with `{2,}`, but that matches consecutive commas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regex pattern:

```
grepl("^[a-z ]+, [a-z]+$", subject, perl=TRUE, ignore.case=TRUE);
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kB4uV1/1)

**Regex Explanation:**

```
^[a-z ]+, [a-z]+$/gmi

    ^ assert position at start of a line
    [a-z ]+ match a single character present in the list below
        Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case insensitive)
         the literal character  
    , matches the characters , literally
    [a-z]+ match a single character present in the list below
        Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case insensitive)
    $ assert position at end of a line
    ignore.case: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Does `^` mean both "starting with" and negation? I got confused when I read this documentation http://laurikari.net/tre/documentation/regex-syntax/

Comment: In this case, the beginning of the line, if inside a character class `[^123]`, negates the characters after it, in this example `123`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the RegEx:  ^([^.,])+,\s([^.,])+$

```
^ assert position at start of the string
1st Capturing group ([^\.,])+
    Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    Note: A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data
    [^\.,] match a single character not present in the list below
        \. matches the character . literally
        , the literal character ,
, matches the character , literally
\s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
2nd Capturing group ([^\.,])+
    Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    Note: A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data
    [^\.,] match a single character not present in the list below
        \. matches the character . literally
        , the literal character ,
$ assert position at end of the string
```

Comment: Thanks, I get this error unless a use a space in place of `\` : `Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""^([^.,])+,\s"`.
Also, would you know how to stick in the regular expression (in the right part) the `state.abb` vector from base R? I didn't explicitly asked for it in the question but I guess it would be a legitimate improvement considering the context.